# how to configure touchpad gestures on Debian 8

Tags: debian, touchpad

Would it be possible to have touchegg (or equivalent) on Debian 8?
Essentially I just need to configure mac-like touchpad gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Touchpad gestures are configured with the `synclient` tool which in Debian can be found in the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package, or can be configured through `Xorg.conf`.

Personally, I run the following in my X session:

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=2 HorizTwoFingerScroll=1 ClickPad=1
```

For a full list of options you can pass, run `man 4 synaptics`

Comment: At a first glance it does not look possible to set a change of workspace with a three fingers scroll. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on your window manager, really. You can configure the touchpad to produce a particular input signal to a three finger gesture. If you can configure your window manager to react to that input signal by changing the workspace, you're done. If not, you may need to switch window manager...

Comment: I can configure a keyboard shortcut to change workspace, but I do not know what is the sintax on synclient for "three fingers scroll down->change of workspace shortcut". Is this any clear?

Comment: There is a tool called `xev` which you can use to see what the effect of the settings you set with `synclient` is. With that, and with the documentation of the synaptics driver as well as your window manager, you *may* find that it is possible. At any rate, you will not find a global 'change workspace' setting; after all, even the concept of what a workspace is and what it can do differs between window managers.